# How to find the value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{9})^k$ using partial sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fractions, geometric-series

So I was trying to prove an infinite sum by looking at the partial sum, when I ran into a problem. Consider: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k =  \frac{1}{8} 9^{-n} (9^n-1)$$

but as there are no solutions to $9^{-n} (9^n-1) = 1$, is it possible to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k = \frac{1}{8}$$ by the partial sum?

Comment: *I ran into a problem* - What problem ? Just expand the parentheses, and let $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right there: You want $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{8}(9^{-n} (9^n - 1))$

Distribute: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{8}(1 - 9^{-n}) = \frac{1}{8}$ since $9^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

The problem you say that you "ran into" seems to be more of a conceptual issue. The problem I believe you're having is that there is no solution to $9^{-n}(9^n - 1) = 1$. This is true, but limits are not exact solutions always. Limits are what a sequence *approaches.* This means that we can get as close as we want, but that doesn't mean that we ever have to get there exactly. Thus, while there are no solutions to $9^{-n}(9^n - 1) = 1$, as $n \to \infty$ the left hand side *approaches* $1$, and that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k\\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{8}9^{-n}(9^n - 1)\\
& = \frac{1}{8} \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - 9^{-n})\\
& = \frac{1}{8}(1 - 0)\\
& = \frac{1}{8}
\end{align*}